# Read column mapped as hidden in XML back to DataSet in VB.Net?

Tags: xml, vb.net, dataset, mapping

I have Dataset and one of its table column is mapped as hidden (.ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden) when writing as XML. When i read back the same XML (readXML) to my Dataset this column remains empty. Is there any way to read those hidden column values back to dataset or those information is lost?

Comment: After writing to xml open the file with notepad and see if column has data.  You probably aren't writing the column to the file so you cannot read something that doesn't exist.

Comment: xml does not show this column. Is it hidden in xml structure or it is not written to xml?

Comment: XML is TEXT so nothing can be hidden.  So when you are reading the Dataset into the xml it is not giving the hidden columns.